# How to check the entire forEach List? (Java)

Tags: java, foreach, boolean

`getNumTel` is the Long Value of the objects.
I would like this method to check the long number values ​​of the ENTIRE array. And it has to return false when the value of `a` is in the array, and return true when any object has a long value like `a`. How do I do that?

```
public static boolean aggiungiPersonaa() {
    Long a = 39354567L;
    ArrayList <Persona>listapersone = new ArrayList();
    listapersone.add(new Persona("Name", "surname", 45, "address", "fbd", 39354567L, "egre"));
    listapersone.add(new Persona("name", "surname", 45, "address", "job", 338959453L, "egre"));
    
    for (Persona persona2 : listapersone) {
        if (a == persona2.getNumTel()) {
            return false;
        }   
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Isn't that what you're already doing, i.e. returning `false` when the value of `a` is in the array list?

Comment: Maybe what I should ask is: What's the difference between "value of `a` is in the array" and "any object has a value like `a`"? They seem to say the same thing to me.

Answer (score 1):

set a bool variable to false on top of the for loop.

if you find a value like a, set the bool to true (u can break the loop here if you want to)

in the end you have boolean stating if your value is in the array.

alternatively you can set a counter and add +1 every time you find something in the for loop